# Одноразовое объявление переменной

Tags: java

В общем, есть код в цикле:

```
public void onEnable(){
    ..........
    getServer().getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(this, new Runnable()
    {
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            Block b = a.get(i);
            if(b.getWorld().getBlockAt(b.getX(),b.getY(),b.getZ()).getType() == Material.AIR){
                int timer = 1;
                timer++;
                getLogger().info("а интов у нас целых " + timer);
                if(timer >= 20){
                    setbl(b.getWorld(),b.getX(),b.getY(),b.getZ(),0.5);
                    timer = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

и в консоли видно, что интов-то у нас всегда 1! В общем, как один раз объявить переменную, чтобы подсчёт на переменных начался?

Comment: Объявить переменную в другом месте

Comment: здесь в другом месте имеется ввиду винести перед циклом

Comment: Вы сам то понимаете то месиво, что выложили в комментарий? Гораздо понятней было бы весь нужный код оформить и вложить в вопрос, вы же можете вопрос редактировать.

Answer (score 2):

У вас счетчик создавался на каждой итерации цикла, поэтому всегда был одинаковый, поэтому нужно было просто вынести его вне цикла:

```
public void run()
{
    int timer = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
        Block b = a.get(i);
        if (b.getWorld().getBlockAt(b.getX(),b.getY(),b.getZ()).getType() == Material.AIR) {
            timer++;
            getLogger().info("а интов у нас целых " + timer);
            if (timer >= 20) {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "а интов у нас целых 1"
"а интов у нас целых 2"
"а интов у нас целых 1"
"а интов у нас целых 2"
*Результат из консоли.
P.S. Мне для каждого блока нужен личный подсчёт времени.
P.P.S. А ничего, что там шедулер вечно подгружает этот цикл и класс?
P.P.P.S. Думаю, шедулер внутри шедулера организовать...

Comment: можете вынести в поле класса

Answer (score 0):

Я вынес в поле класса "стартовую" переменную, после чего при создании блока и записании его в массив, записывал в отдельный массив этот int под тем же номером, что и сам блок. В итоге, работает, при чём довольно стабильно.